# How to read text files inside Archive file format (Rar/Zip) without extracting the Archive file using 'C' only?

Tags: c, windows, zip, archive, rar

I have tried finding the solution for the problem on google but unable to find a solution that supports both the Archive formats i.e Rar/Zip.I tried debugging with 7zip [7zip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sevenzip/files/LZMA%20SDK/lzma920.tar.bz2/download?use_mirror=kaz/%227zip%22) but it has functions that compress/decompress or extracts the contents of Archive files , I could not find any Functions that reads the text files inside Archive,While searching for the solution I found minizip supports both the formats Rar/Zip with [minizip](http://code.google.com/p/miniz/downloads/detail?name=miniz_v115_r4.7z)

I tried to debug the minizip and tried open the text file inside Archive,but it failed.

At Last i tried looking at the Zlib code which is a dll [zlib](http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/minizip.html//%22%22) , but a function to read text file from Archive was not there.

So, can you please guide as how to move ahead in this task .

**Making the requirement clear again**

I just want to read the content of text files inside archive (rar/zip) For e.g I have Archive C:\Test.rar and Test.rar contains filesample.txt , so my requirement is to read the content of filesample.txt directly ,I dont want to extract the files.

Comment: We can can read text file from archive by including miniz.c and in the miniz code download here https://code.google.com/p/miniz , there is example2 that solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Download WinRar (that is what I am using).

Open the archive with it

Select the *.TXT file

Press the forth button **VIEW**, or ***Alt+V***.

Voila. Hope it helps.